# How to track subfolders using git?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo that contains subfolders -- Repo 1

I cloned also my repo from Azure Devops -- Repo 2

What I did is copy the folders from Repo 1 inside Repo 2 and do "git add ."

After "git commit" and "git push orign master" I can only see in my Repo 2 a file with the HEAD number... No folders and subfolders has been tracked.

Is there any easy way to do what i need? Just copy Repo 1 that contains a tree structure inside Repo 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Git does not track directories, it only tracks files.

Comment: @HenriMenke: more precisely, the OP already *made* a submodule (or what I call a "half-assed submodule": one missing the `.gitmodules` entries); perhaps they don't actually want this (but we can't tell).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any easy way to do what i need? Just copy Repo 1 that
> contains a tree structure inside Repo 2.

There is.  You can clone Repo 2 and put whatever files you like in that local clone of the repo.  If the files you put there happen to be copied from Repo 1, Git doesn't have to know or care about that.  As far as Repo 2 is concerned, they are just files being added to the repo and their origin story is of no consequence.  Once you copy the files into the Repo 2 clone, if you stage the new files, commit them, and then push that commit to a remote (the original Repo 1 remote or a whole different remote, doesn't matter, then the newly added files will be in that repository.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. However not sure If I followed you correctly. Steps to follow according to your suggestion are: 1-Clone locally remote Repo2.  2-Copy folders and files from Repo1 to locally cloned remote Repo2. 3-Stage and commit. 4- Push changes to Remote Repo2 (from Azure Devops). If you mean this, I have already done that but folders are not tracked. No folders are pushed to remote Repo2. Also Git gives me a warning about folders and subfolders...

Comment: @XT oh, it gives warnings? Why haven't you included the warnings in your question? It would save everybody a lot of time and you'd get a useful answer faster. Also, if there are warnings (that applies to any software): read and understand them instead of ignoring them